# Using Python from a command window: Setting the PATH variable on Windows 8: Picture Provided

Tags: python, variables, path, cmd

> As of now only this works:
>
> set path=C:\Python34
>
> But this has to be done each and every time cmd is opened.

I am trying to set a permanent variable

I tried following the below steps but I do not have a Variable "Path" so i cannot click to edit it. Please look at the picture screen shot. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

http://postimg.org/image/i8z8y8wcv/

```
press Start
select Control Panel
On the Control Panel window, in the left column, press Switch to classic view (If you don't see this text, go to the next step below.)
Double click on the icon for System
In the System window, click on Advanced
Click on the button Environment Variables
In the new window, scroll until you see the variable, Path; click on it
Press Edit
Carefully use the right arrow button to move to the end of the long sequence of folder names. At the very end, without including any extra blanks, type this:
;C:\Python24
```

Comment: Any Python Guru out there that can help with this?

Answer (score 3):

[image: Setting path variable]

You need to edit the path variable in the system variables section. Add the following to the end of the variable value :

`C:\Python34\;C:\Python34\Scripts;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to configure Python for all users on your computer
(by changing the **System** environment variable), just scroll up a few clicks. 
The variables are listed in alphabetical order by name,
so PATH should be just a few notches above PSModulePath. 
(Note that modifying System environment variables requires that you have Administrator privilege.) 
Or, if either you’re not privileged or you need to set this up only for yourself,
create a **New** user variable
by clicking on “New…” in (under) the “User variables for Roo” section. 
Enter the name as `PATH` and the value as `C:\Python34`. 
If, in the future, you need to add other directories to your PATH,
separate them with semicolons,
e.g., `C:\Python34;C:\Cobra42;C:\Panda17`.